# how to get ranking first variable is object in first object and there is array in second object in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

this is my API.

```
   results: {   this is my api.
    Team: [
    {
     first object.
    TeamId: {   team id.
    status: "1",
    content: "21"  this is done
    },
    TeamName: "United Arab Emirates",
    ShortName: "UAE"
    Ranking: {   how to get ranking this is object but scroll down this is      array. how to get value of content by both section .
    content: "14"    get it
    },
    },
    {
     //second object.
    TeamId: {   teamid done
    status: "1",
    content: "1188"
    },
    TeamName: "Afghanistan",
    ShortName: "AFG",
    Ranking: [   this is array how to read it in android.
    {
    content: "10"   get it
    },
    {
    content: "9"   get it
    }
    ],     add ranking in different variable like a=10,b=9. 
    },
```

Comment: JSONObject tt20=saris.getJSONObject("Ranking");
t20 = tt20.getString("content");
JSONArray rank=saris.getJSONArray("Ranking");
JSONObject t201=rank.getJSONObject(0);
 t20=t201.getString("content");
JSONObject odi=rank.getJSONObject(1);
Odi=odi.getString("content");
 JSONObject test=rank.getJSONObject(2);
content=test.getString("content");
adapter_data.add(new TeamModel(TeamId,TeamName,ShortName, content, t20,Odi));

                    }

Comment: update your format because in first object,Ranking as jsonobject and in second object Ranking as array

Comment: above is my Java code to get json object

Comment: Ranking: {
mtype: "T20",
ranker: "icc",
trend: "steady",
content: "14"
},

Comment: Ranking: [
{
mtype: "Test",
ranker: "icc",
trend: "steady",
content: "1"
},
{
mtype: "ODI",
ranker: "icc",
trend: "steady",
content: "1"
},
{
mtype: "T20",
ranker: "icc",
trend: "steady",
content: "6"
}
],

Comment: this is look like this chek my api

Comment: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20cricket.teams&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2F0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0&callback=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this

firs we get the Team array

```
JSONArray teamArray=result.getJSONArray("Team");
```

then we iterate over the teams

```
for(int i=0;i<teamArray.length();i++)
{
    Object ranking=teamArry.getJSONObject(i).get("ranking");
```

depending on its an array of rankings or just a single JSONObject ranking

```
    if(ranking instanceof JSONObject)
    {
      //get the data
    }
    else if( ranking instanceof JSONArray)
    {
      //get the data
    }
}
```

Comment: if(ranking instanceof JSONObject) {

 JSONObject tt20 = saris.getJSONObject("Ranking");
 t20 = tt20.getString("content");
 }else if (ranking instanceof JSONArray) {
JSONArray rank = saris.getJSONArray("Ranking");
JSONObject t201 = rank.getJSONObject(0);
 t20 = t201.getString("content");
JSONObject odi = rank.getJSONObject(1);
Odi = odi.getString("content");
JSONObject test = rank.getJSONObject(2);
content = test.getString("content");
 }     im getting data like this...

Comment: when you get the array you can thet the first object like this

Ranking: [ { mtype: "Test", ranker: "icc", trend: "steady", content: "1" }, { mtype: "ODI", ranker: "icc", trend: "steady", content: "1" }, { mtype: "T20", ranker: "icc", trend: "steady", content: "6" } ],
if you want the first rank of the  in this case ranker:"icc" you get it like this 
arrayRankig.getJSONObject(0).getString("ranker");
with the cero you get the first Jsonobject in the array and from that object you get the string value of ranker is that what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

First Create arraylist to store yout data

```
 ArrayList<List_items> list_items_arr = new ArrayList<List_items>();
```

Create class for Lisr_items

```
  public class List_items{
   String item_id,item_name;
public void setItem_id(String item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

public void setItem_name(String item_name) {
    this.item_name = item_name;
   }
}
```

get the response from server and parse it

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(json);

JSONArray items = jsono.getJSONArray("Ranking");

  for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++){
         JSONObject list_obj=items.getJSONObject(i);
            List_items list_items = new List_items();
            list_items.setItem_name(list_obj.getString("mtype"));
            list_items.setItem_id(list_obj.getString("trend"));
     list_items_arr .add(list_items);
 }
```

Comment: i want only content...what is item id....and i want t20 content in t20 variable and Test content in test variable and Odi content in odi variable..

Comment: use your own variable name what you want,i said an only example

Comment: but u dont see my json code i have alrady done like this...

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value {"content":"14","ranker":"icc","trend":"steady","mtype":"T20"} at Ranking of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.  im geting that error